# Detect which function is called in another function with the dev tool

Tags: javascript

I would like to be able to recognise which function is called when an action is executed. I know you can do "Inspect element", "Event listeners" and look for the function in the "click" category, the problem is that the site is made so that each action calls the same function which should probably be the entire source code.

So, is it possible to use the same tool on a specific function?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a breakpoint to the function and when the code executes, you can see the `call stack`, you can see all the parent functions.

[image]

Comment: I have succeeded but I get functions marked "(Anonymous)", what does this mean?

Comment: If the function doesn't have a name, it will be anonumous.